# trigonometry short question

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $\cot 10°, \cot 30° \text{and} \cot 80°$.

Comment: What have you tried to answer the question (solve the problem)? Do you know what cot is? Is this something they want you to do with a calculator, or do they want some exact result? What are your own thoughts? What is your math level? Include much more info in a question.

Answer (score 3):

To find exact values (which is what I think you're asking). Use the relations:

$$\sin(A \pm B)= \sin A\cos B\pm\cos A\sin B$$
$$\cos(A \pm B)= \cos A\cos B\mp\sin A\sin B$$
$$\tan(A \pm B)= \cfrac{\tan A \pm \tan B}{1 \mp \tan A \tan B}$$
$$\cot \theta =\cfrac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}$$

So $\cot 30^{\circ}=\cfrac{\cos 30^{\circ}}{\sin 30^{\circ}}=\cfrac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{\frac12}=\sqrt{3}$

Using the above relations you can show that $$\cos 80^{\circ}=\sin 10^{\circ}$$ and $$\sin 80^{\circ}=\cos 10^{\circ}$$

So $$\cot 80^{\circ}=\tan 10^{\circ}$$

and $\tan 10^{\circ}$ is a root to this cubic equation: 
$$3x^6-27x^4+33x^2-1=0$$ once you have $\tan 10^{\circ}$ you can easily find $\cot 10^{\circ}$ via the reciprocal relation: $\cot 10^{\circ}=\cfrac{1}{\tan 10^{\circ}}$

Comment: @anjanakumari Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \cot \ {10}^\circ \approx 5.67128182 \\
\cot \ {30}^\circ \approx 1.73205081 \\
\cot \ {80}^\circ \approx  0.17632698
$$

Comment: These are not rational numbers, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants exact values; anyone can pump $\cot 10^{\circ}$ into a scientific calculator.